# Open Java CLI after is is already running

Tags: java, server, minecraft

I have an instance of Java that runs at startup. It is for a Minecraft Server for my kids. Normally, if you run the command to open the Minecraft Server, a CLI specifically for that Java instance opens and it allows you to interface with Minecraft. However, since I run it as a task, the CLI does not open (this is the outcome I want). Is there a way to open the CLI (on Demand) for this Java instance once it is running. Currently, I have to stop the instance and then manually start it to get into it and then when I close the box it dies so then I run the task again to get it to open for the kids. Any help is appreciated and my kids thank you as well!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about Minecraft but it looks like you can use a so called "rcon" client to connect to a Minecraft server.

[image]

I found one [here](https://github.com/Tiiffi/mcrcon). There is [one for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrcon/) (in screenshot above) as well.